# What is the logic behind this sequence limit proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The question is:

[image: Question]

The solution given is:

[image: Solution]

Is there some mistake with this solution? I understand that the limit is $\frac{3}{2}$, but their reasoning, to me, falls short of proving this.

What I don't understand is why they solved for N and then subbed it back in the equation, immediately after deriving it to find that $\epsilon = \epsilon$. Then they use this trivial fact as the reasoning behind $\frac{3}{2}$ being the limit (as n approaches infinity).

If I would use another number--other than $\frac{3}{2}$ (not the limit as n approaches inifinity)--I could repeat the process and get the same result.

Comment: 1) No you could not, and 2) notice that the last displayed equation shows that $|a_n-3/2|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: "Falls short of proving this." How, exactly? They didn't find $\epsilon=\epsilon$, they found that if $n>N$ then $|a_n-\frac{3}{2}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I think it falls short of proving the first equation where they write, the limit of f(n) as n approaches infinity is 3/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we tried to prove the same way that the limit was $1$.

Then $$|a_n-1| = \frac{n+8}{2n-1}$$

Now we already see a problem - if we try to solve $\frac{n+8}{2n-1}<\epsilon$, what do we get:

$$n+8<\epsilon(2n-1)\\
8+\epsilon < (2\epsilon-1)n$$

But wait, now for small $\epsilon$, $2\epsilon-1<0$ so this means that:

$$n<\frac{8+\epsilon}{2\epsilon-1}$$

So we get the opposite of what we want, at least for $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$. Then, for large $n$, we find that when $n>0>\frac{8+\epsilon}{2\epsilon-1}$, that $|a_n-1|>\epsilon$. So the limit is *not* one.

It's worth noting that, in the above the middle part of the proof is completely necessary - you could prove this even without that middle part. The middle part is just how you derive the formula for $N$. The actual proof is:

> Show $$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\frac{17}{4n-2}$$
>   Given $\epsilon>0$, let $N=\frac{17}{4\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> Then show if $n>N$ then $\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\epsilon$.

The middle part is just the way you derive $N$, but it isn't necessary for the proof. In other words, *of course* you've picked exactly the $N$ you needed. That is the point.

Comment: I really like this answer because you've shown me why other values will not work for the limit--since in other situations there could be values of $\epsilon$ that result in N being less than 0. I also wasn't aware that $\epsilon$ did not have to be an integer. I'm pretty sure I understand this answer, but, just to confirm, this proves, without a doubt, that the limit of f(n), as n approaches infinity, is 3/2?

Comment: It's not that $N<0$ - that wouldn't be a problem. The problem is that, because we need to divide the inequality by $2\epsilon-1<0$, we *switch the order of the inequality.* So that it now is only true for $n<N$, not for $n>N$. @Klik

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the definition of a limit as $n$ (or whatever the variable is) goes to infinity formalizes the notion that as long as you make $n$ is big enough, the result of the expression will be as close to the limiting value as you like.

What is presented as the proof is really two parts: (a) the analysis to determine how large $n$ must be for the result to be within $\varepsilon$ of the limiting value, and (b) showing that if you make $n$ that large, you really do get a result that is that close to the limiting value.  They are in a sense mirror images of each other, but only part (b), starting with "Well, now if we let...", is the actual proof.

Maybe a simpler expression will make this process clearer.  Suppose we want to establish that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$.  The bare bones proof—corresponding to part (b) above—runs as follows:

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be any positive number.  Then let $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, and for any $n > N$, we have $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} = \varepsilon$, and the limit is established.  (That is, for any margin of error $\varepsilon$ you care to choose, we can make $N$ large enough that $\frac{1}{N}$ falls within that margin around $0$.)

That's all that's really needed.  But how did we determine $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$?  We do that through analysis, analogous to part (a) above: by asserting $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$, and seeing how large $N$ must be so that all $n > N$ satisfy that inequality.  That gives us the expression for $N$ that we use in the actual proof.

Here, the symmetry is so evident that it seems almost trivial.  In the original problem, it's not quite as obvious (though it should become more so, with increased exposure).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is perfectly fine. Usually, when you are trying to prove a limit by definition, you have to have a limit candidate (say $l$). The usual steps to prove a limit by definition are the following:

Take an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$, (this number is any positive number, that you have already fixed, you won't be able to change it along the proof)

Now that we have fixed our $\epsilon$, and we have our limit candidate $l$, we should find a natural number $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$

In this case, our $\varepsilon$ is fixed, and we have to find a natural number $N$ that will make that $\frac{17}{4n-2} <\varepsilon$ if $n \geq N$. That is the reason they leave $n$ on its own in the inequality. Because, once you set $N=\frac{17}{4\varepsilon}+ \frac{1}{2}$, then taking $n \geq N$ you have that $|a_n - 3/2|=\frac{17}{4n-2} < \varepsilon$.